# How to show multiple text and text position in Python Plotly stacked bar chart

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, plotly, plotly-express

I am displaying the individual value in the stacked bar. I also like to show the total of each stacked bar in the top. Is it possible to do?

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Make':['Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'BMW', 'Chrysler', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Mercedes'],
                          'Dimension':['Styling', 'Styling', 'Price', 'Styling', 'MPG', 'MPG', 'Styling', 'Styling', 'MPG', 'MPG', 'Price', 'Price', 'Styling', 'MPG'],
                          'Country':['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'England', 'Germany', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Poland', 'Italy', 'USA'],
                          'LowValue':['64', '61', '70', '65', '59', '68', '63', '57', '58', '55', '69', '63', '69', '61']})
df_make = df.groupby(['Make','Dimension']).count()[['LowValue']].reset_index()

fig = px.bar(
    data_frame=df_make,
    x='Make',
    y="LowValue",
    color="LowValue",
    text="LowValue",
    
)
fig.update_traces(textposition='inside')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there's no way to do this directly. But you could always use `fig.add_annotation()` with a setup like this:

```
for i,t in enumerate(totals):
    fig.add_annotation(x=x_uniq[i], y = t,
                       text = str(t),
                       showarrow = False,
                       yshift = 12,
                       font=dict(family="Courier New, monospace",
                                 size=18,
                                 color="firebrick"
                                )
                      )
```

Where `x_uniq` are the unique occurences `['BMW', 'Chrysler', 'Mercedes']` of the figure's x-values `['BMW','BMW', 'BMW', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes']` and `totals` are the corresponding partial sums of the figure's y-values `[1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2]` mapped to the x-values. The complete snippet below contains all details on how to get those values and produce this figure:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

df = pd.DataFrame({'Make':['Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'BMW', 'Chrysler', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Mercedes'],
                          'Dimension':['Styling', 'Styling', 'Price', 'Styling', 'MPG', 'MPG', 'Styling', 'Styling', 'MPG', 'MPG', 'Price', 'Price', 'Styling', 'MPG'],
                          'Country':['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'England', 'Germany', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Poland', 'Italy', 'USA'],
                          'LowValue':['64', '61', '70', '65', '59', '68', '63', '57', '58', '55', '69', '63', '69', '61']})
df_make = df.groupby(['Make','Dimension']).count()[['LowValue']].reset_index()

fig = px.bar(
    data_frame=df_make,
    x='Make',
    y="LowValue",
    color="LowValue",
    text="LowValue",
    
)
fig.update_traces(textposition='inside')

L = list(fig.data[0].x)
x_uniq, x_counts = np.unique(L, return_counts=True)
y_vals = fig.data[0].y
y_vals


elements = list(x_counts)

totals = []
index = 0
for i, e in enumerate(elements):
    if i == 0:
        totals.append(sum(y_vals[0:e]))
        index = index + e
    else:
        totals.append(sum(y_vals[index:index + e]))
        index = index + e
totals

for i,t in enumerate(totals):
    fig.add_annotation(x=x_uniq[i], y = t,
                       text = str(t),
                       showarrow = False,
                       yshift = 12,
                       font=dict(family="Courier New, monospace",
                                 size=18,
                                 color="firebrick"
                                )
                      )
fig.show()
```